# Kibbud Av v'Eim Seforim

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Would anyone know of an English *sefer* on *Kibbud Av v'Eim* which Has a mix of Halacha and Mussar ?

Answer (score 5):

ArtScroll has a book titled "[The Fifth Commandment](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191918.html)" that sounds like it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend two seforim in particular:

- [Yalkut Yosef, Kibbud Av Va'em](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?P_ID=3766&strPageHistory=related) by Rabbi Yitzchak Yosef, son of
  Maran Hagaon R. Ovadia Yosef, (Etbonan Publisher, 2006) and
- [Honoring Parents in Halachah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568713347) by  Rabbi Tzuriel Taaseh (Targum
  Press, 2004).

Both of them has a collection of midrashim and mussar sayings from chazal.

Answer (score 0):

The book [My Father, My Mother and Me - Sons and daughters tell of their devotion, challenges, and successes in honoring their parents](http://www.eichlers.com/my-father-my-mother-and-me-hardcover.html) by Yehudis Samet (Artscroll), is really great!